# How to display wp_list_categories on div instead of li?

Tags: categories

Does anyone know how to display the [`wp_list_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) on a `div` instead of the `li`?

I basically want to wrap main categories and its children in a bootstrap column.

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'           => 'product_category',
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
    'title_li'           => 0
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the `style` argument as something other than the default (which is `list`) and it won't wrap the output in a `<li>`. You can then wrap it in a `<div>` yourself.

Combine it with the `echo` argument if you need to check that the list isn't empty. Example:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'           => 'product_category',
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
    'title_li'           => 0,
    'style'              => '',
    'echo'               => false,
);
$categories = wp_list_categories($args);

if ( $categories ) {
    printf( '<div class="col">%s</div>', $categories );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please add two new argument into your `$args` array.

1) Style with none value. See the markup section for [more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Markup_and_Styling_of_Category_Lists).
2) echo with 0(False).

Now call and store the result into `$categories` variable and print it via `printf()`.

Final code like:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'           => 'product_category',
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
    'title_li'           => 0,
    'style'              => 'none',
    'echo'               => 0,
);

$categories = wp_list_categories($args);
if ( $categories ) {
    printf( '<div>%s</div>', $categories );
}
```

In aditional,  you can use `if ( !preg_match( '/No\scategories/i', $cats ) )` If the displayed text reads "No categories".

P.S. If this stuff helps you please leave me a comment and support :)